# HTTP Accept negotiation algorithm

Tags: http

I am readying HTTP spec document for the `Accept` header and encountered with the following example.

```
Accept: text/*, text/html, text/html;level=1, */*

# Precedence
1) text/html;level=1
2) text/html
3) text/*
4) */*
```

I am wondering what algorithm is used to sort the preference of each content-type? Is there any standard documentation for it? Any reference to some implementation or documentation will be appreciated.

Is it correct to say that under the same quality factor, more specific content-types have higher precedence (`application/json` > `application/*`)?

How come `text/html;level=1` has higher preference `text/html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at an obsolete spec. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#header.accept for the current one.

In particular:

"Media ranges can be overridden by more specific media ranges or specific media types. If more than one media range applies to a given type, the most specific reference has precedence..." -- https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.5.3.2.p.10